# Count 'OK' instances in a word table using data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-docx

Hello I am trying to count the 'OK' instances in a specific cell in a word table. Here is my code:

```
from docx2python import docx2python
import pandas as pd

doc_result = docx2python('Results3.docx')

counterOK = 0
counterNOK = 0

df = pd.DataFrame(doc_result.body[0], columns= [0,1,2,3])
print(df)

req = df.loc[9][1]
print(req)

if (req == 'OK'):
    counterOK+=1
elif (req == 'NOK'):
    counterNOK+=1
else :
    (print('sad'))

print(counterOK)
print(counterNOK)
```

Why do I always end up in the else branch?

Here is the [Word Table](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rFue9kAlTZ9aK4BG8o7FtyGcya9C_SeawDZeaKPL-mI/edit) I used.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I always end up in the else branch?

Because `req` always looks at `df.loc[9][0]`. Instead [iterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) through the dataframe.

Eg.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[1] == 'OK':
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: Yes I know, I intend to look in this specific location for now. I will create the loop later on by changing this line df = pd.DataFrame(doc_result.body[i], columns= [0,1,2,3]) to access several tables. Right now print(req) prints: ['OK'] however the if condition isn't fulfilled.

Comment: @Nemo `['OK']` is not the same as `'OK'`. Look At @Krish answer as he indexes the row `row[1]`.

Comment: Hmmm. Try `print(type(req))` and check whether it is a string class or list class. If `req` is an iterable just read out the first value of `req`

Comment: @Krish It's a list class. I followed your advice and changed the code to `if (req[0] == 'OK')` and it works now. Thanks a lot.